# Microsoft Graph is too fast for B2C Custom Policy updating user details

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a web application which is integrated with B2C. When I take the user away to edit their details - eg: update their name. After clicking continue, the user is redirected back to the application.

When the application hits the OnSecurityTokenValidated method, I am querying the Microsoft Graph API to get the user's full details including name. If they updated their name in the B2C edit profile screen, then sometimes the Microsoft Graph API is still returning their old name (what it was before it was updated).

So it appears that B2C hasn't saved the changes back to the AD user before Microsoft Graph API then queries the same AD user. Is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD architecture is a distributed design where writes are eventually consistent so you might be reading from a directory replica before it is written to.

For more information, see [What is the Azure Active Directory architecture?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-architecture)

You might want to issue and read the user properties from the ID token.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case, thanks for confirming this!